# Decode Jwt token React

Tags: reactjs, jwt

I use jsonwebtoken to decode my Token to see if it has expired or not. But, the console.log return null.

```
 var token = response.headers.authorization;
 token = token.replace('Bearer','');
 var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
 var decoded = jwt.decode(token);
 console.log(decoded);
```

I'm don't understand because my token is not null

Comment: What prints console.log(token) after line 2?

Comment: Print my token value : eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJkeWxhbi5uYXRpZXJAYmx1ZXNvZnQtZ3JvdXAuY29tIiwiZXhwIjoxNTQ1MjMyMTUxfQ.4t7fCh3Ux8qJo8xVC3HvsQKx3q0ulfOQclJmGf4vcAu77xoFwboPAjHil1ASfZRr_S7PviM354PdLgioPeiL4g

Comment: Thee package `jsonwebtoken` is intended for use on the backend. For the frontend, you should use `jwt-dcode` which is developed by the same company (auth0) but is much more smaller and intended for frontend use.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

It seems like you are using JWT. To decode this type of token you can simply use [jwt-decode library](https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode). For example, in ReactJS:

```
import { jwtDecode } from 'jwt-decode' // import dependency
// If using v3 or earlier, use this instead:
// import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode' // import dependency

// some logic
axios.post(`${axios.defaults.baseURL}/auth`, { email, password })
    .then(res => {
      const token = res.data.token;
      const user = jwtDecode(token); // decode your token here
      localStorage.setItem('token', token);
      dispatch(actions.authSuccess(token, user));
    })
    .catch(err => {
      dispatch(actions.loginUserFail());
  });
```

Comment: What are the pros and cons of doing this compared to decoding it on the server, basically sending the token from the client to the server and then it returning the info? What's better arquitecturally speaking?

Comment: **IMPORTANT:** This library doesn't validate the token, any well formed JWT can be decoded. (source: official repo)

Comment: My problem is the same as this one, but I want to access the data I keep in the token, such as user role, name and surname. How can I do these?

Answer (score 7):

Assuming your header is something like `Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c`
then after line 2 you have a leading space.
See the below example for the difference the leading space makes. Trimming the leading space should resolve your issue.

```
var jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

var token1 = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c";
var token2 = " eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c";

var decode1 = jwt.decode(token1);
var decode2 = jwt.decode(token2);

console.log("without leading space");
console.log(decode1);
// { sub: '1234567890', name: 'John Doe', iat: 1516239022 }

console.log("with leading space");
console.log(decode2);
// null
```

Answer (score 4):

Try `jwt-decode` in Library react

**Install jwt-decode Library**

```
npm i jwt-decode
```

**Sample Code**

```
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";

const token = "eyJ0eXAiO.../// jwt token";
const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
console.log(decoded);
```

Answer (score 2):

It may be as simple as removing the extra space that your pasted sample would leave. The authorization header is `<scheme><space><value>` so:

```
`var token = token.replace('Bearer ','');`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try jwt-decode in Library react. here is the link to npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode

**Installing jwt-decode Library**

npm i jwt-decode

**usage:**

```
import jwtDecode from "jwt-decode";

const token = "eyJ0eXAiO...OyEwXg";
const payload = jwtDecode(token)
console.log(payload)
```